# Minimum removals from array to make max – min <= K

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

Given N integers and K, find the minimum number of elements that should be removed such that Amax-Amin<=K. After removal of elements, Amax and Amin is considered among the remaining elements.
Examples:

Input : a[] = {1, 3, 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 20} 
          k = 4 
Output : 5 
Explanation: Remove 1, 3, 4 from beginning 
and 17, 20 from the end.

is this code correct??

https://pastebin.com/viEhuH4V

```
   #include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n,i,j,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    int arr[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)cin>>arr[i];
    sort(arr,arr+n);
    for(i=0,j=n-1;i<n,i<j;){
        if(arr[j]-arr[i]>k){
            if(arr[j]-arr[i+1]<=k)
            {i++;break;         }

            else if(arr[j-1]-arr[i]<=k)
            {j--;break;         }

            i++;
            j--;
        }
        else
        break;
    }

    cout<<i+n-1-j<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Run some test cases through it and find out.

Comment: yeah thats the problem ,for test cases that come to myh mind its working fine but how can i be sure that it is universally correct.

Comment: That's an excellent question in general about testing code. You can either mathematically prove that BOTH 1. your algorithm is correct and 2. your code actually implements you algorithm, or you can pick a proxy measurement: Say run X number of random (or guided tests), or test for X number of hours, and if no bugs have been found in that time, then assume it's "good enough".

Comment: i see but can you pls show me how do i mathematically prove it

Comment: Do you have a problem? Or are you just asking for a code review?

Comment: @Mohit I have no idea how.

Comment: @PaulFloyd im looking for a code review

Comment: In that case https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be more appropriate